# Why is the switch statement to be avoided in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

One of my teachers said that we should avoid using the switch statement.
Why?  what's bad about it?

Comment: Actually that is not true. Once an if statement passes in a large if else ladder it will execute that block and exit to the bottom

Comment: you teacher is wrong.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would think your teacher thinks the syntax is a little weird for new students (every case needs a `break` in it which can be forgotten). But you shouldn't just avoid something because it can be confusing. You'll just go a long time being unnecessarily afraid of switch statements. In programming, different situations require different solutions. In some instances, a switch statement is much easier than if-else.

Comment: @karina you are right!

Comment: Ask your teacher why. How are we supposed to know how he arrived at that conclusion? It's certainly unusual.

Comment: @bpgeck with eclipse nowadays you shouldn't be worrying about forgetting the break part. I think there is a different reason for not recommending the switch.

Comment: @Thilo too late... I was trying to see if there is any experienced person here who can answer the question

Comment: I suspect your teacher is not contrasting `switch` vs. `if`, rather [conditional logic vs. polymorphism](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

Comment: Since it's "too late" to ask the teacher chalk this up as a lesson learned. Any  time an instructor says something is bad, question them. Why do they thinks it's bad (or good for that matter)? Do they have any evidence to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instructor may have been trying to keep you guys from falling into a situation where you use a switch statement as a crutch! There are situations where they are appropriate, but often they are used to hard-code something that is better-handled with polymorphism.

For example:

```
Car c = getCar();
switch(c){
  case FordCar:
    driveFordCar();
    break;
  case ToyotaCar:
    driveToyotaCar();
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

would be better-handled by putting an abstract method driveCar() in the abstract class or interface Car, then implementing it in FordCar and ToyotaCar. If you want to add support for Volkswagen cars, think about how much cleaner it would be to add an implementation for driveCar to your new VolkswagenCar class (the compiler will complain if you don't!) instead of having to remember to update your case statement.

Comment: This only works if `Car` is an enum. Or you could use an `int` of course.

Answer (score 0):

There are uses for both if/elseif/else and switch statements. Neither is better or worse than the other as they would most likely be converted to the same/similar bytecode by the Java compiler.

When an if or elseif condition is matched, the code inside that block is executed, and then the code skips to the end of the if/elseif/else "ladder". In a switch statement, when a condition is matched, the code will continue from that matched "case" until a "break;" is found. In this way, it is possible to execute any other matched conditions.